# How to take data from two different database and show in single table?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a **database A** with **Table X**. In table X data is stored 1 seconds wise.
Like

```
---------------------------------
      timestamp     |col1 | 
--------------------------------- 
2019-02-25 21:42:00 | 10  | 
2019-02-25 21:42:01 | 20  |
2019-02-25 21:42:02 | 12  | 
2019-02-25 21:42:03 | 0   |
2019-02-25 21:42:04 | 14  |
```

data is stored second wise till last event is off. ie. 2019-02-25 21:55:04

Other database is **B** with **table Y**. it stores events data.

---

```
      timestamp     | event|
---------------------------- 
2019-02-25 21:42:00 | On   |
2019-02-25 21:43:25 | Off  |
2019-02-25 21:46:21 | On   |
2019-02-25 21:49:03 | Off  |
2019-02-25 21:50:00 | On   |
2019-02-25 21:55:04 | Off  |
```

So i have to take data of only On and Off events from Table X. And show it in the SSRS report.

### **Expected Result :**

```
      timestamp     |col1|
---------------------------- 
2019-02-25 21:42:00 | 10 |
2019-02-25 21:43:25 | 5  |
2019-02-25 21:46:21 | 13 |
2019-02-25 21:49:03 | 9  |
2019-02-25 21:50:00 | 17 |
2019-02-25 21:55:04 | 8  |
```

How can i do this using single SQL query?

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: mysql ? or sql-server ??

Comment: sql-server @scaisEdge

Comment: @TusharWalzade I have taken the top 1 event timestamp from Y table and passed it to the query in condition. but i am not able pass middle events.

Comment: I personally don't see the logic on your expected col1. How do you calculate it ?.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you just wanted a simple join between these 2 table

```
SELECT y.timestamp, x.col1
FROM   B.dbo.TableY y
       INNER JOIN A.dbo.TableX x ON y.timestamp = x.timestamp
```